# Correct way to iterate over Keras ragged tensor

Tags: tensorflow, keras, input, efficientnet, ragged-tensors

I have an input Tensorflow ragged tensor structured like this `[batch num_images width height channels]` and I need to iterate over the dimension `num_images` to extract some features relevant for downstream applications.
Example code is the following:

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.efficientnet import EfficientNetB7
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
import tensorflow as tf


eff_net = EfficientNetB7(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
input_claim = Input(shape=(None, 600, 600, 3), name='input_1', ragged=True)
eff_out = tf.map_fn(fn=eff_net, 
                    elems=input_claim, fn_output_signature=tf.float32)
```

The first `Input` dimension is set to `None` as it can differ across data points, and for this reason the input receives instances of `tf.RaggedTensor`.

This code breaks with a `TypeError` in this way `TypeError: Could not build a TypeSpec for KerasTensor(type_spec=RaggedTensorSpec(TensorShape([None, None, 600, 600, 3]), tf.float32, 1, tf.int64), name='input_1', description="created by layer 'input_1'") of unsupported type <class 'keras.engine.keras_tensor.RaggedKerasTensor'>.`
I suspect there is a better way to perform this type of preprocessing though

Update: `num_images` is needed because (although not described here) I am doing some following `reduce` operation on this dimension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tf.ragged.map_flat_values` to achieve the same

Create a model like:

```
def eff_net(x): #dummy eff_net for testing that returns [batch, dim]
    return tf.random.normal(shape=tf.shape(x)[:2])

input_claim = keras.Input(shape=(None, 600, 600, 3), name='input_1', ragged=True)

class RaggedMapLayer(layers.Layer):
    def call(self, x):
        return tf.ragged.map_flat_values(eff_net, x)

outputs = RaggedMapLayer()(input_claim)

model = keras.Model(inputs=input_claim, outputs=outputs)
```

testing,

```
inputs = tf.RaggedTensor.from_row_splits( tf.random.normal(shape=(10, 600, 600, 3)), row_splits=[0, 2, 5,10])
#shape [3, None, 600, 600, 3]

model(inputs).shape
#[3, None, 600]
```